# mysql insert and update using primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has 5 columns.
4 columns will remain the same, only the 5th column changes.

```
a  b   c   d   e

v1 v2  v3 v4  v10
v1 v2  v3 v4  v11
v1 v2  v3 v4  v12
v1 v2  v3 v4  v13
v1 v2  v3 v4  v14
v1 v2  v3 v4  v15
v6 v7  v8 v9  v16
v6 v7  v8 v9  v17
v6 v7  v8 v9  v18
v6 v7  v8 v9  v19
v6 v7  v8 v9  v20
```

The first 4 columns will always have the same values, only 5th column value will change.

I am making the columns a,b,c,d as primary key and trying the collowing statement.

```
INSERT INTO $tablename( a,b,c,d,e)
                VALUES(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE e = VALUES(e);
```

The result that I get is:

```
a  b   c   d   e

v1 v2  v3 v4  v15
```

What I am trying to have in my database is:

```
a  b   c   d   e

v1 v2  v3 v4  v10
              v11
              v12
              v13
              v14
              v15
v6 v7  v8 v9  v16
              v17
              v18
              v19
              v20
```

Comment: cool, so what's your question?

Comment: If the first 4 columns are a,b,c,d, then "The first 4 columns will always have the same values" and "columns a,b,c,d as primary key" are contradictions. One of those statements must be false.

Comment: so on `DUPLICATE KEY` you want to insert a new row with `a,b,c,d` as `null`, and only `e` with a value? (based off your last example)

Comment: Yes Sean. That's what I am trying to do.
I am trying to save space in my db, by not duplicating records in columns a,b,c,d. I am not sure, if I need to use 2 tables to achieve this or just one.

When I use the above code, I get only the column e updated with last value, i.e e =v15.

Comment: why even have those 4 columns if they are always the same?

Comment: The first 4 columns are going to be used as a combination to extract column 5.
eg: (a,b,c,d) --> v10

By using a,b,c,d I am trying to pull data out of v5.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a primary key contain null values.  If (a,b,c,d) is your primary key, it must have non-null values on every row.  And it can't have all the *same* values, because a primary key must be unique.

You misunderstand what `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does.  It means that if there is already a row existing in the table with the primary or unique key you're trying to insert, *it does not insert a new row*, but instead changes the existing row according to your SET assignments.

It sounds like you have a one-to-many relationship, and you need a second table for that.

> The first 4 columns are going to be used as a combination to extract column 5. eg: (a,b,c,d) --> v10 By using a,b,c,d I am trying to pull data out of v5.

I can't understand what you mean here.  Not only does the primary key *not* "pull data out of" attribute columns, but you mention v10 and then v5 and so it's not clear what you're doing.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo,meant , I was trying to pull out data out of column e.

Thanks for the update, I did notice that, the INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE was only updating, the column 'e' . 
Yes, I actually need to insert a new record everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You have a one-to-many relationship between your primary key (abcd) and the value (e). So for each (abcd) you have many (e)s. This can not be done using one table, as you can not have duplicate primary keys in one table.

Basically you need to create (at least) two tables instead of one, namely:

Table1: a, b, c, d, i1 (with (abcd) as primary key)
Table2: i2, i1, e (with i2 as primary key) [Alternative: only i1, e with (i1,e) as PK]

Here i1 is the link between your data sets. So you'll have one row for each (abcd) in Table1, together with some unique i1. Then for each e that is associated with the (abcd) you create one row in Table2 containing the respective i1 and e.

Comment: Ok cool . Thanks. I have been trying to create the same thing, but I am stuck at creating the link. Could you please provide me with an example.

Comment: @rishirich The link (i1) is just some unique integer. Start at 0 or 1 and increase it every time you insert a new (abcd) in Table1. This is necessary as you use a composed primary key. If you had a single-value PK in Table1 you could have used the PK instead.